# Copy sequential files from multiple folders into new folders

Tags: windows

I'm using Windows 10 and working with multi-camera video footage. I'm going to use an example to best explain.

### Example

I've been on a shoot with 6 cameras all shooting the same scene at once.  I dump the footage and end up with 6 separate folders (a folder per camera), and each folder has an equal number of shots, or "takes".

The camera "takes" are numbered sequentially, though each camera has its own individual name. The files in Camera A folder might be called GOPR0023, GOPR0024, GOPR0025, while those in the Camera B folder might be called GOPRO0111, GOPR0112, GOPRO0113.

### I'd Like

What I then want to do is create folders for each "take"...for example folder `~\Take1`, which includes "take 1" from cameras A, B, C, D, E, F, etc.

How can I do this with the least effort in windows 10?  When I have 6 camera folders with 20 takes each, it takes ages to do this manually.

Essentially, I'd like a tool which takes the first file (take 1) from each camera folder that cuts and pastes them into a new folder, and repeats (next sequential take/file) until no files are left.

Comment: Do it with a bat file, hopefully someone here will demonstrate exactly how.

Comment: The absolute easiest solution would be to pay a developer to write a tool for you. (Doesn't even need to be an experienced developer.)

Comment: The absolute best solution is to learn to do it on your own while the easiest would be to ask someone that knows what they're doing that'll just help you and is reliable (paying them or not). In terms of paying for the service vs going to what a Q&A site means, I understand your intention implicitly when I read your questions on this site. With the vast libraries of robust tools at the disposal of developers even an inexperienced developer could do it, so become one yourself why don't you so you never have to ask again... lol!!

Comment: The camera takes are sequentially numbered, though each camera has its own individual name (for example the files in Camera A folder might be called GOPR0023, GOPR0024, GOPR0025, while those in the Camera B folder might be called GOPRO0111, GOPR0112, GOPRO0113).  Unfortunately the file sizes for each take are different from camera to camera, as this would make it easy to group them.   

Because the takes are named sequentially, what I need is essentially a tool which takes the first file from each camera folder and cuts and pastes them into a new folder, and repeats until no files are left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Copy sequential files from multiple folders into new folder (Win 10)**
>
> I've been on a shoot with 6 cameras all shooting the same scene at
>   once. I dump the footage and end up with 6 seperate folders (a folder
>   per camera), and each folder has an equal number of shots, or "takes".
>   What I then want to do is create folders for each "take"...for example
>   Folder Take 1, which includes take 1 from camera A, B, C, D, E, F etc.

Below are two examples of how to complete what you are stating in your question that have been confirmed to work as you explain in my test environment.

One script **will NOT delete the original takes or files from each of the 6 camera's source folders** and the other one **will delete the original takes**—I wasn't sure if you wanted to delete the original source file takes afterwards or not so I provided one with and one without.

You will need to plug in the variables for your need in the batch script logic of the below examples. You will save these to a text document (meaning everything in either one of those that you decide to use - each one is a separate script / text file though), and then name it `<something>.cmd`. Once it's a `cmd` named file and you have your variables plugged in, it's just a matter of double-clicking to launch it to do what you ask.

**Variable Notes**

I added comments to the batch scripts clarifying the variables you'll need to set (just variables) and the folder names for the first [**FOR**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop but to clarify further:

- Where it is listed as `SET CameraRootDir=` this will need to be set to equal the full path root level folder where ALL the camera folders exist. It is assumed they are all in the same ONE standard folder and from there they all have their own folder such as `CameraA`, `CameraB`, and so on.
- Where it is listed as `SET TakeRootDir=` this will need to be set to equal the full path level folder where you want the `Take1`, `Take2`, `Take3`, and so on folders to exist.
- Where you see the `FOR %%C IN (` logic, just beneath that you will see the below listed items of `CameraA`, `CameraB`, and so on. This will each equal the ONE folder name ONLY where each Camera# will be the name of the one and only unique folder names beneath the parent folder where all those exist. Just replace each of those with the **camera folder names** where the takes or sequential files are saved—**LEAVE THE COMMAS though**.

  > ```
  > CameraA,CameraB,CameraC, 
  > CameraD,CameraE,CameraF
  > ```
- If your camera folders are located on the root of the "C" drive as `C:\CameraA`, `C:\CameraB`, and so on, then you will want to be sure the `SET CameraRootDir=C:\` just like that so it will equal `C:\` and the above folder names (above bullet point quoted items) you list in that part of the logic will iterate through the six in case that helps clarify; otherwise, the full path (if not the ROOT of the "C" drive) will be the PARENT\ROOT folder containing those folders.
- It is also assumed the FIRST shot or image file in each unique camera folder will be `Take1` and the next after that `Take2` and so on in that sequential order so that's how I have the logic set now in the below examples.

**Other Notes**

Please take a moment and look here ([**Accepting An Answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)) to familiarize yourself with accepting answers on Super User and other Stack Exchange communities for that matter. If this works for your needs, accepting the answer would be appreciated for gratitude.

### Batch Script No Delete

```
@ECHO ON
::: --// The CameraRootDir variable is the root level variable just beneath each separate camera folder name
::: --// The TakeRootDir variable will be the folder location just beneath take1, take2, and so on will be created
SET CameraRootDir=C:\Path\Cameras
SET TakeRootDir=C:\Path\CopiedTakes
IF NOT EXIST "%TakeDir%" MD "%TakeDir%"

::: --// Each item below separate by a comma is the camera folder names just beneath the root level name
::: --// You will need to replace these entries with the actual camera folder name for each of your 6 cameras
FOR %%C IN (

    CameraA,CameraB,CameraC,
    CameraD,CameraE,CameraF

) DO (

    SET TakeCount=0 
    CALL :CAMERA_MODE "%%~C"

)
GOTO EOF

:CAMERA_MODE
SET CameraDir=%CameraRootDir%\%~1
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%T IN (

    '"DIR /B /A-D /OD "%CameraDir%\""'

) DO (

    CALL :TakeMove "%%~T" "%~1"

)
GOTO EOF


:TakeMove
SET /A TakeCount=%TakeCount%+1
IF NOT EXIST "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%" MD "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%"
ECHO F | XCOPY /F /Y "%CameraDir%\%~1" "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%\%~2_%~1"
GOTO EOF
```

### Batch Script with Delete

```
@ECHO ON
::: --// The CameraRootDir variable is the root level variable just beneath each separate camera folder name
::: --// The TakeRootDir variable will be the folder location just beneath take1, take2, and so on will be created
SET CameraRootDir=C:\Path\Cameras
SET TakeRootDir=C:\Path\CopiedTakes
IF NOT EXIST "%TakeDir%" MD "%TakeDir%"

::: --// Each item below separate by a comma is the camera folder names just beneath the root level name
::: --// You will need to replace these entries with the actual camera folder name for each of your 6 cameras

FOR %%C IN (

    CameraA,CameraB,CameraC,
    CameraD,CameraE,CameraF

) DO (

    SET TakeCount=0 
    CALL :CAMERA_MODE "%%~C"

)
GOTO EXIT

:CAMERA_MODE
SET CameraDir=%CameraRootDir%\%~1
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%T IN (

    '"DIR /B /A-D /OD "%CameraDir%\""'

) DO (

    CALL :TakeMove "%%~T" "%~1"

)
GOTO EOF


:TakeMove
SET /A TakeCount=%TakeCount%+1
IF NOT EXIST "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%" MD "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%"
ECHO F | XCOPY /F /Y "%CameraDir%\%~1" "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%\%~2_%~1"
DEL /Q /F "%CameraDir%\%~1"
GOTO EOF
```

---

### **Further Resources and Reading**

- [**SET**](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [**CALL**](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [**IF**](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [**XCOPY**](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

Comment: Lost for words..... that was amazingly helpful and totally works.  You are a downright legend.  Thanks so much, really didn't expect someone to put in so much time to help me, but you did and I am very grateful.  Thanks mate, you've helped me a lot!  Thank you.

Comment: Hi LMFAO, this tool is awesome.  I was wondering, would there be a simple change which would allow the files to be cut and pasted, rather than copied?  The copying, because the files are large, takes a lot of time.  If I could cut and paste them it would be a much faster.  

I did some research and tried changing the XCOPY to MOVE, but it didnt seem to work for me...?

Comment: @user543144 Be sure to test first just in case but try this: Remove this line `ECHO F | XCOPY /F /Y "%CameraDir%\%~1" "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%\%~2_%~1"` and put this line in its place instead `MOVE /Y "%CameraDir%\%~1" "%TakeRootDir%\Take_%TakeCount%\%~2_%~1"`. I've NOT tested this so please be sure to test it. Also see [**MOVE**](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) for additional reading and research. The ECHO and all have to be replaced but this should be the syntax from what I collect but I'll not be able to test right now. Let me know if you still have trouble with it.

Comment: @user543144 See my comment above but if the MOVE command in that place replacing that line works, you will ALSO want to remove the line from the script with delete with the logic of `DEL /Q /F "%CameraDir%\%~1"` Just delete that line so the `GOTO EOF` is in its place. I typically `COPY` or `XCOPY` and then delete in case there's a network issue, disk, etc. issue that the original will still be there to be copied over on the next run or whatever so just know that is a possibility  to occur with `MOVE` rather than `XCOPY`.

Comment: @user543144 Feel free to look over some of my other answer if those are helpful to you, up vote one or so. Just click on my profile, go to answers, and you'll see ones I've answered and I've gotten quite a few batch scripts I've written to help people with certain tasks. Don't up vote a bunch of them quickly though just one or two only or it'll be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

if you *don't* want to go for installing or coding a tool:

- do a search across the tree in Explorer
- sort the result accordingly
- select and drag and drop the files that belong together in their target directory.

Anything more comfortable needs some software or batch, which might exist or might not.